# ¿Cómo testear el código que se encuentra dentro de la función anónima de un callback en Node.js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, pruebas-unitarias, callback

Soy bastante nuevo con **Node.js**. Ahora me encuentro escribiendo las pruebas unitarias con **Mocha** y **Chai** pero me he quedado atascado cuando se trata de probar el código que se encuentra dentro de las funciones anónimas que sirven de callback para las funciones asíncronas.

He escrito un ejemplo para explicar la situación. Tengo las siguientes funciones asíncronas de ejemplo:

```
asyncAddition = function (a, b, callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        callback(a + b);
    }, 3000);
}

asyncSubstraction = function (a, b, callback){
    setTimeout(() => {
        callback(a - b);
    }, 3000);
}
```

y las quiero usar dentro de un método `calculate` de una clase que no toma ningún callback en sus argumentos. Sólo toma 2 operandos `a` y `b` y una cadena para indicar qué operación se desea hacer, que se realizará asíncronamente y pone el resultado en el miembro `result`:

```
class Example{

    constructor(){
        this.result = null;
    }

    calculate(a, b, action){

        if (action == "add") {

            asyncAddition(a, b, (result) =>{
                this.result = result;
                console.log("Addition result is: " + result);
            });

        }
        else if (action == "substract") {

            asyncSubstraction(a, b, (result) =>{
                this.result = result;
                console.log("Substraction result is: " + result);
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Dado que el valor de `result` se establece dentro del código del callback, ¿cómo puedo escribir una prueba para el método `calculate` que compruebe los valores de `result` dependiendo de los diversos operandos y la operación?

¿Alguien puede indicarme brevemente el código de la prueba (p.ej. con Mocha/Chai que es lo que utilizo) para hacerlo basado en mi ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Si tenemos en cuenta que `asyncAddition` y `asyncSubstraction` son funciones "privadas", estás no deberían ser testeadas y lo que deberías testear es la implementación del método `calculate` de tu clase.

Dicho de otra manera, el test lo deberías hacer sobre el método `calculate` probando con los diferentes parametros `action` que acepta como parametro ( "add" y "substract") con distintos valores en A y B.

Si en cambio asumimos que `asyncAddition` y `asyncSubstraction` son funciones publicas que quieres testear, bastaría con hacer algo así:

```
it('Debe devolver 2', function(done) {
  asyncAddition(1,1 (result) => {
    expect(result).to.be.equal(2);
    done();
  });
});
```

Espero sirva de ayuda!

Comment: Testear el método **calculate** con diferentes parámetros es precísamente lo que estoy pidiendo en mi pregunta. El problema es, como digo, que no sé cómo comprobar el valor final del miembro **result** para esos parámetros, dado que se establece de forma asíncrona.